# Load data from api in chunks in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I need help with Vue loading data. I get data from api, and I need to make chunks of that data. When I load component I need to load first 20, than second 20, so on.. How I can make chunks of array without using any external npm library?

Comment: have you implemented paging on the API? i.e pass up `?page=1&limit=20` if you have that then you can use [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to look for a specific element underneath the 20 items and when its shown, increment the page, then in a watcher watch the page model and when it changes recall the API  `?page=2&limit=20`, then concat the items, i.e `this.items = this.items.concat(resp)`, if no items in previous response then flag a model to not call again, possibly unhook the observer, is quite a bit to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily read this documentation from [You dont need...](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_chunk)

They have a very useful example of how to make a chunk replacemente for any external library:

**Chunk:**

```js
const chunk = (input, size = 1) => {
  return input.reduce((arr, item, idx) => {
    return idx % size === 0
      ? [...arr, [item]]
      : [...arr.slice(0, -1), [...arr.slice(-1)[0], item]];
  }, []);
};
```

**Output**

```js
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
// => [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 3);
// => [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']]
```